# Delete last char of a "Get-Content | Get-Random" output

Tags: powershell

I want to delete the last char of an output

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 9
[string]$mails = ""

$recipient = Get-Content F:\maillist.txt  | Get-Random -Count $random
$mails = $recipient + $mails

return $mails
```

This gives out:

```
name2@domain.com,
name6@domain.com,
name8@domain.com,
```

This is good, but I need to get rid of the last "," because that's the variable I want to use in order to send a mail via `Send-MailMessage`

I've tried a few things:

```
$recipient = Get-Content F:\mailliste.txt  | Get-Random -Count $random
$recipient_conv = $recipient.Remove($recipient.Length-1)
```

This cuts off completely like: `nam @do ...`

```
$recipient_conv = $recipient.TrimEnd(",")
```

This works but then there is no "," at all, like: `name1@domain.com name3@domain`

But I need the "," to tell `Send-Mailmessage` there are more then one recipient.

The same result as `.TrimEnd()` is with this:

```
$recipient_conv = $recipient -replace ".$"
```

The mailinglist is looking like this:

```
name1@domain.com,
name2@domain.com,
name3@domain.com,
...
name9@domain.com,
```

**EDIT** **EDIT** **EDIT** **EDIT**

@Manu @AnsgarWiechers

The code looks like this

```
$random = Get-Random -Minimum 1 -Maximum 9
[string]$mails = ""  

$recipient = Get-Content F:\mailliste.txt  | Get-Random -Count $random

$recipient_conv = $recipient.TrimEnd(",") -join ', '

$mails = $recipient_conv + $mails

Send-MailMessage -To $mails -From sender@domain.com -Subject "This is a subject" -Body "This is the bodytext"
```

This will send mails, but just to only one instead of all randomly grabbed mailadresses. If i get mysef the output like `Write-Host "send to: $mails"`

it will say: `send to: name3@domain.com, name6@domain.com, name1@domain.com`

so everything seems to be fine, so whats the problem

Comment: Did you try to use `TrimEnd` on `$mails`?

Comment: in this line : $mails = $recipient + $mails.TrimEnd(",")  < NO EFFECT - In this line : return $mails.TrimEnd(",") < only if the ouput is 1 mailadress

Comment: Why not just create an array of recipients instead of concatenating strings together? Isn't it that great benefit of PowerShell, that it's object oriented?

Comment: The string might have a whitespace in the end as well, does `$mails.TrimEnd(' ',',')` work?

Comment: The `-To` parameter of `Send-MailMassage` accepts a string array as input. `$recipient.TrimEnd(',')` should do just fine as long as you don't mangle the address array to a single string before passing it to `Send-MailMessage`. Otherwise use `$recipient.TrimEnd(',') -join ','`.

Comment: -join ',' did the trick! But know it seems that only the last mailadress will actually be send.. i think i just did the mangle? How can i manage to get send-mailmassage to send those others? I´m a bit confused

Comment: @EdgarEckstein `Send-MailMassage`? It's confusing us :-) You should be more specific as we answer and are not able to clearly find what you are looking for. I think it misses some code that we can't guess and that makes your question unclear.

Comment: Did you try without `-join` and `+ $mails`? Just `$mails = $recipient.TrimEnd(","); Send-MailMessage -To $mails ...` should work just fine.